# Alguém pode me explicar essa parte em JSON por favor?? (Wordpress Plugin)

Tags: json, wordpress

Galera, bom dia, vou detalhar o máximo da minha dúvida para ver se alguém consegue me entender e me ajudar... Eu tenho o seguinte Plugin instalado no Wordpress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-google-spreadsheet-viewer/

Este Plugin cria esta parte no Cpanel do Wordpress:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E está parte cria estes três botões no frontend:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém como eu edito estes botões?? Por exemplo se eu quiser adicionar um CSS neles ou personalizar com mais coisas em HTML, como faço??

Se eu tentar adicionar qualquer código HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT no backend da primeira imagem a cima o painel simplesmente não permite, no caso eu teria que fazer em JSON?? Mas não entendo nada de JSON, enfim preciso de uma ajuda.

Segue um vídeo breve com mais detalhes (o vídeo tem áudio ele começa em 27 segundos):  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWUVQPgQ6Cg

Comment: isso está carrendo dentro de uma iframe ? ou  direto no  DOM do html ?
se for dentro de uma iframe não tem como alterar nada, se for direto no html  você pode ir acessando  ele atravez dos elementos parents exemplo      div > span > li > .algumaclass .button {style aqui}

Comment: carrega direto no HTML sem iframe... Mas não tem como modificar aquele campo no Cpanel do wordpress para aceitar HTML??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este campo que vc editou não é para HTML, é o config inicial do [DataTable](https://datatables.net/), incluido no código utilizando CDN, conforme [código no respositório](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/inline-google-spreadsheet-viewer/trunk/inline-gdocs-viewer.php)

para personalização, o plugin oferece a possibilidade de adicionar classes, como neste exemplo com shortcode

```
[gdoc key="ABCDEFG" class="my-sheet" title="Tooltip text displayed on hover" summary="An example spreadsheet, with a summary."]This is the table's caption.[/gdoc]
```

veja que foi incluído a classe `my-sheet`, que você pode colocar o que quiser e usar para estilizar, pois irá gerar o html como

```
<table id="igsv-ABCDEFG" class="igsv-table my-sheet" title="Tooltip text displayed on hover" summary="An example spreadsheet, with a summary.">
    <caption>This is the table's caption.</caption>
    <!-- ...rest of table code using spreadsheet data here... -->
</table>
```

com isso vc cria uma as regras em seu css, como por exemplo:

```
.my-sheet{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas além do css preciso adicionar o HTML, essa parte já pesquisei muito mas não achei uma solução.

Comment: @DanielFortunato não sei se entendi corretamente, mas vc quer adicionar o select, para abrir diretamente uma planilha baseado no estado, certo, porque não adicionar este select como shortcode e usar na página, assim já faz o redirect para onde achar que deve, na página de destino deixa aparecer os botões e a pessoal exporta como for necessário, como é a página no final?